# Returning and Summing the Odd Numbers of an Array

Tags: java, arrays, return

I'm trying to add all the odd numbers in an array and return it. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Example:

Input:

Array- [12,6,7,15,1]

It would return 23

```
 public static int sumOdds(int[] numbers) {
            sum = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                if (numbers%2==0) 
                return 0;
                else (numbers[i] % 2 != 0) {
                    sum += numbers;
                    return sumOdds; 
                    }
            }
```

Comment: What is `numbers % 2 == 0` supposed to do?  `numbers` is an array, not a number.  Even if you meant to check a value in the array, do you really want to return `0` if there is *any* even number in the array?

Comment: Also, you're supposed to sum up all the numbers. But you are returning as soon as you find an even or an odd number

Comment: @azurefrog I want to return 0 if there are no odd numbers in the array

Comment: Your Code can‘t compile. You Return sumOdds wich is a method but you Miss the Parameter.

Comment: `return 0` is going to end your for loop and exit the method the very first time that a value in your array is even.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static int sumOdds(int[] numbers) {
   int sum = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
       if(numbers[i] % 2 != 0) {
           sum += numbers[i];                
       }
   }         
   return sum;
}
```

This should work. `return` statements should not be within your `if` and `else` statements, as they will end the execution of the program immediately.

Comment: Then change the name sum to sumOdds? sum returns 23 here, isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: This is almost the correct solution. You simply need to initialize sum with a type, `int sum = 0;`. What does "I need to return it to sumOdds" mean?

Comment: sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

And a Java 8+ solution would be

```java
  public static int sumOdds(int[] numbers) {
      return Arrays.stream(numbers).filter(n -> n % 2 == 1).sum();
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

There are a few issues here. First of all, the mod operation is not going to work on an array. It needs to be performed on a single number. Furthermore, you are immediately returning the sumOdds without allowing the entire loop to complete.

This would work.

```
public static int sumOdds(final int[] numbers) {
    int sumOdds = 0;
    for (int number : numbers) {
        if (number % 2 != 0) {
            sumOdds += number;
        }
    }
    return sumOdds;
}
```

Or better yet, use streams.

```
int sumOdds = IntStream.of(12, 6, 7, 15, 1).filter(number -> number % 2 != 0).sum()
```